# NPM installing package removes another

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-install

When i install a package with npm install for my react-native project it automaticly removes another. How can I stop this from happening?

[image]

Comment: try to save in package.json/package.lock with --save. Example: npm install --save react-native-sliding-up-panel

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you've added a git dep, possibly using a branch identifier like: **git+https://..../you/your_project.git#your_branch** but after resolution it's saved in package-lock.json not as **#your_branch** but as **#sha**_for_latest_commit_to_your_branch. When npm tries to resolve this difference it gets confused and removes what you've got currently.

You can get around the npm bug, while we wait for a fix to land, by copying that sha from package-lock.json into your package.json. You'll need to change the sha in package.json any time the dep gets more commit(s) pushed that you want in your project....

This would be annoying if you wanted it to automatically pick up changes to a frequently changing git dependency, but at least it would stop the uninstall behavior.. by Adam Tuttle ... cant see more in this link https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17379